# Get pixels from a CUDA graphics resource

Tags: opengl, cuda

How can I obtain a pixel buffer object and get the RGB pixels into an array, given a CUDA graphics resource?  Could somebody provide an example or confirm if my own attempt is correct? The existing code looks like this:

```
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &render_cuda_pbo_resource, stream));
    uchar4 *d_output;
    size_t num_bytes;
    cutilSafeCall(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void **)&d_output, &num_bytes, render_cuda_pbo_resource));
```

I have added the following code:

```
    glBindTexture  (GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex);
    glPixelStorei  (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (-1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f (1.0, -1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTexCoord2f (0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f (-1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glReadPixels(10, 10, width, height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

OpenGL objects are OpenGL objects; CUDA objects are CUDA objects. If you want CUDA to put stuff into OpenGL objects, you must *give* CUDA OpenGL objects and have it put the stuff into them. This is generally done with [`cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__OPENGL_g43f69a041bdfa4f8b36aff99bf0171db.html).

Comment: Thanks! And how would that fit into the existing code I have?